# How to remove double quotes and extra delimiter(s) with in double quotes of TextQualifier file in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a lot of delimited files with Text Qualifier (every column start and end has double quote). Delimited is not consistent i.e. there can be any delimited like comma(,), Pipe (|), ~, tab (\t).

I need to read this file with `spark.read.textFile` (single column) and then remove Text Qualifier along with delimiter (need to replace delimiter with space) with in double quotes. Here I want do with out considering columns i.e. I should not split into columns

Below is test data with 3 columns ID, Name and DESC. DESC column has extra delimiter.

```
val y = """4 , "XAA" , "sf,sd\nsdfsf""""
val pattern = """"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"""".r
val output = pattern replaceAllIn (y, m => m.group(0).replaceAll("[,\n]", " "))
```

I got above code which works fine for static value. But I am not able to apply to DF.

> "ID","Name","DESC" 
>   "1" , "ABC", "A,B C" 
>   "2" , "XYZ" , "ABC is bother" 
>   "3" , "YYZ" , "FER" sfsf,sfd f" 
>   4 , "XAA" , "sf,sd sdfsf"

I need output as

> ID,Name,DESC 
>    1 , ABC , A B C
>    2 , XYZ , ABC is bother 
>    3 , YYZ , FER" sfsf sfd f 
>    4 , XAA , sf sd sdfsf

Thanks in Advance.

**Resolved**

```
var SourceFile = spark.read.textFile("/data/test.csv")
val SourceFileDF= SourceFile.withColumn("value", RemoveQualifier(col("value")))
def RemoveQualifier = udf((RawData:String)=>
  {
    var Data = RawData

    val pattern = """"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"""".r

    Data  = pattern replaceAllIn (Data , m => m.group(0).replaceAll("[,]", " "))
   Data 
  })
```

Thanks.

Comment: Avoid to reuse variable for holding more than one value. It is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can two replaceAll() like this use like this:

`val output = pattern replaceAllIn (y, m => m.group(0).replaceAll("[,\\\\n]", " ").replaceAll("\"|\"", ""))`

> output: String = 4 , XAA , sf sd  sdfsf

Comment: Need one more thing I don't want to remove double quote which is with in set of doulble quotes EX: 5,"TES","SFSFSF"sdfsf" this should be modified to 5,TES,SFSFSF"sdfsf rather than 5,TES,SFSFSFsdfsf

Comment: Can you please provide this solution using pyspark?

Comment: @Jay Sorry I don't have any experience with the pyspark.