# csv file contains data with special chars including comma(,) , (\) and (" ") .Unable to create df with correct no of columns? -py-spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a CSV file and I want to create a data frame with that in py-spark, but unable to do so as some of the rows contain data with special characters and half of its columns are double-quoted. Below is the data and what I tried so far.

sample_row

```
"ABG090D",2019-03-03 00:00:00.0000000,"A","some Data C\" AB01","Some Data","LOS","NEW",2019-04-11 00:00:00.0000000,"GHYTR","7860973478","0989","A",2019-03-03 00:00:00.0000000,"Y","N","N","N",1,"N","D016619",,"$,$#,&","Y",
"69901",,,,"FGF",89.00,"W",,"N","R","F",5.00,6.00,6.00,9.00,2.00,0,0,"9090",,"N",,,"1","N",,,"F",,2019-03-03 00:00:00.0000000,,,,,"N","A","N","N","N","N","N",,,,,,,"H",,,,,,,,,,"N","A","0","0","0",,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"N","00","USA",
"C","I",0,,,,"FGF",0,,,"N","UOIU","5",,0,,0,0,,,"878","N",2019-04-11 09:44:00.0000000,"8980909","H",,,,"N","2","T","SomeData",
2020-03-12 09:24:52.0000000
```

In the above data the 2 major problems I am facing are:

1.**"some Data C\" AB01"** => as it contains backslash() as well as quotes(") as a part of data.

2.**"$,$#,&"** => as it contains comma(,) as a part of data

```
df = spark.read.option("quote","\"").option("escape","\"").option("escape","\\").option("delimiter" , ",").option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true").csv("/path/file.csv",customSchema)
```

With the above code, I was able to solve **"some Data C\" AB01"** but the second column ie. **"$,$#,&"** is creating a problem here.

Even I tried to use the answer given in the below link. But it is also not working for me.
[How to remove double quotes and extra delimiter(s) with in double quotes of TextQualifier file in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581739/how-to-remove-double-quotes-and-extra-delimiters-with-in-double-quotes-of-text)

Comment: it would be better to describe why spark.read.csv("path") does not work for you; how many columns you expect etc.

Comment: Total number of columns I expect is 129 but if I use simple spark.read.csv("path") then it gives me more than 129 columns ex "$,$#*&" gets converted into 2 columns i.e. $ and $#*&

Comment: spark version? in 2.4.5 it seems to work fine - I got 129 columns

Comment: 2.4.3 but not getting correct results

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off building your own parser in your case. I wrote a simple one shown below using a regular expression to parse the file and store the values in the `values` list.

Hopefully this approach will work for you.

```
import re

regex = r"(\"([^\"]+)\",?|([^,]+),?|,)"

test_str = "\"ABG090D\",2019-03-03 00:00:00.0000000,\"A\",\"some Data C\\\" AB01\",\"Some Data\",\"LOS\",\"NEW\",2019-04-11 00:00:00.0000000,\"GHYTR\",\"7860973478\",\"0989\",\"A\",2019-03-03 00:00:00.0000000,\"Y\",\"N\",\"N\",\"N\",1,\"N\",\"D016619\",,\"$,$#,&\",\"Y\", \"69901\",,,,\"FGF\",89.00,\"W\",,\"N\",\"R\",\"F\",5.00,6.00,6.00,9.00,2.00,0,0,\"9090\",,\"N\",,,\"1\",\"N\",,,\"F\",,2019-03-03 00:00:00.0000000,,,,,\"N\",\"A\",\"N\",\"N\",\"N\",\"N\",\"N\",,,,,,,\"H\",,,,,,,,,,\"N\",\"A\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,\"N\",\"00\",\"USA\", \"C\",\"I\",0,,,,\"FGF\",0,,,\"N\",\"UOIU\",\"5\",,0,,0,0,,,\"878\",\"N\",2019-04-11 09:44:00.0000000,\"8980909\",\"H\",,,,\"N\",\"2\",\"T\",\"SomeData\", 2020-03-12 09:24:52.0000000"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
values = []

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
  if match.group(3) != None:
    values.append(match.group(3))
  elif match.group(2) != None:
    values.append(match.group(2))
  else:
    values.append(None)

print(values)
```

Comment: It is also not working for me, getting 132 columns expected 129. \"some Data C\\\" AB01\ should come as a single column but getting two. Also **\"$,$#,&\"** should come as a single column but getting two.